# Conditional in shell script

Tags: shell

```
OS: ubuntu 14.04
```

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rsp $'Press Y/y to execute script or any other key to exit...\n' -n1 key
if [ "$key" != 'y' ] || [ "$key" != 'Y' ] ; then
    echo 'You did not press the y key'
    exit
fi
echo 'some other stuff'
```

No matter what key I press, it always echoes "You did not press the y key"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `&&` instead of `||` as logic should say:

```
if key is not 'y' AND if key is not 'Y' then: error
```

**Code:**

```
if [ "$key" != 'y' ] && [ "$key" != 'Y' ] ; then
    echo 'You did not press the y key'
    exit
fi
```

If you're using `bash` then you can shorten that to:

```
if [[ $key != [yY] ]]; then
    echo 'You did not press the y key'
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Duh, yes. Too early in the morning. Is the [[]] necessary for the shortened code, or can I use only one set of brackets?

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper You need `[[...]]` to use a pattern as the RHS of `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

What anubhava said.  Also, `case` might be a good alternative to your `if` statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -rsp $'Press Y/y to execute script or any other key to exit...\n' -n1 key

case "$key" in
  Y|y)
    echo 'You DID press the y key. Proceeding.'
    ;;
  *)
    printf "I can't handle the '%s' key!\n" "$key"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

echo 'some other stuff'
```

Incidentally, except for the `read` options, this is POSIX-compatible, so it's more portable than bash-only code (like anything using `[[ ... ]]` conditions).